# how to save a drawingpad image in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

#### UPDATE

now its working, see the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983621/2844901)

this is my getDrawing function, I need to save the signature from drawing to a file in file system, I've tried everything and I cant get the saveToFile demo in nativescript docs to get it work.

```
exports.getDrawing = function(args) {

    var pad = frameModule.topmost().currentPage.getViewById("drawingPad");
    // then access the 'drawing' property (Bitmap on Android) of the signaturepad
    var img = frameModule.topmost().currentPage.getViewById("imagesignature");

    pad.getDrawing().then(function(result){
    img.src = result; // <-- this shows in an image label the drawing signature
    ########### this part should be save the file,but I don't get any error, and it doesn't save it to a file, when tried to dump "img" ############
     var img2 = imageSource.fromAsset(result);
     var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
     var path = fs.path.join(folder.path, "Test.png");
     var saved = img2.saveToFile(path, "png");

  
});
```

}

Comment: What's "not working"?  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: I did update the "not working" and can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was, the getDrawing() does not return a promise it returns an image so the correct code should be a NativeSource.

```
pad.getDrawing().then(function(result){
    img.src = result;
    console.log("1");
    var img2 = imageSource.fromNativeSource(result);
    var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
    var path = fs.path.join(folder.path, "Test.png");
    var saved = img2.saveToFile(path, "png");
    console.log("saved: " + saved);
    console.log("IMAGEN SRC.....");
});
```